# How do I automatically open a subfolder on a SD card when mounted?

Tags: automator

My camera has a complicated path to the video files, and I'm constantly plugging it in, and then digging to get the videos.  I just want find to automatically popup to the specified subfolder when the card is mounted.

I've install DSW (Do Something With from Azarhi), but I'm not sure how to set up Automator to open a new finder window with the specific location?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

With automator you can do this. It'll open a Finder window with the specified folder selected :
[image]

You could also make an alias of the folder, and when you plug the SD card in you just need to open the alias and it'll bring you to the desired location. Right click on the original folder and Select Make Alias and put the alias somewhere easily accessible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an AppleScript applet could do the trick, as you can set one to start when a card or camera is connected in the Image Transfer app.

What does a typical path look like? Is the name of the card always the same from card to card?